# How to use va_args to pass arguments on (variadic parameters, ellipsis)

Tags: objective-c

I can't get my head around the syntax for multiple arguments in Objective-C. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710033/what-is-this-objective-c-syntax-ellipse-style-dot-notation), but the answer hasn't helped me (yet).

Here is my code (actually I will want to eventually pass to NSString stringWithFormat, but getting an NSLog to work would be good enough for now):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
     // Insert code here to initialize your application 
     [self log:@"blah blah %d", 32];
}


- (void)log:(NSString *)text, ... {
      va_list args;
      va_start(args, text);
      NSLog(text, args);
}
```

The argument (or some argument) comes through, but it's got some weird value (output is `blah blah 1606412704`). How should I pass the values that come in via `...`?

Comment: Related to, but not quite a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345196

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a variant of `NSLog` that accepts a `va_list` called [`NSLogv`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIGDBJC):

```
- (void) log:(NSString *)text, ... {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, text);
  NSLogv(text, args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

The only way to forward the actual `...` (not the `va_list`) is to use a macro.  For example:

```
#define MyLog(f, ...) { \
NSLog(f, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
[someObject doSomething:f, ##__VA_ARGS__]; \
}
```

However, this should be used very sparingly, since macros can make code *really* obfuscated.

Comment: That is cool and +1, but I still don't know how to pass the args to the next method (or maybe I am doing it right?)

Comment: You can't. Once `...` is converted to `va_list`, it can be only passed to a function or a method which accepts `va_list`, not to a function/method which accepts a variable number of parameters.

Comment: @Yuji, ooooooooooooooooo lemme try that out.

Comment: Thanks @Yuji, that worked. So there's no way to pass the variable number of params (in other words, I MUST convert it to a va_list)? Also, if you want to put your comment in an answer, that would help.

Comment: @yar you can only forward the `...` in non-`va_list` form inside macros.  (`##__VA_ARGS__`)  (Edited answer w/ more info)

Comment: Thanks. The macros are even more obfuscated by SO's formatting above. So that's pretty cool. I should've asked the questions in a more generic way, to get better more generic answers. What I'm really interested in is how to get and pass `...`. I get it now, though: the method that gets it can only pass it as a va_list or using macros, which is bad practice.

Comment: @yar the `##__VA_ARGS` only applies to the list of items passed into the macro, not passed into the function/method.  Once they're inside a function/method, the only way to extract them is via a `va_list`.

Comment: @yar Indeed. That's why there's a whole series of functions with and without `v` in the standard C library, like `printf` and `vprintf`.

Comment: Thanks again Dave DeLong and @Yuji. I'm learning C accidentally via Objective-C, so most of this stuff is news to me.

Answer (score 12):

You could use [`-[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithFormat:arguments:):

```
- (void)log:(NSString *)text, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, text);
    NSString *log_msg = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:text arguments:args] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@", log_msg);
}
```

Comment: Wow. While that doesn't answer my question, it solves my current problem. How would you pass the args to the next method, though?

Comment: You can't pass the variable parameters. You can pass `args`, but that means the function or method has to take an object of type `va_list`.

Comment: Okay, that is very cool. I ended up doing this `- (void)log:(NSString *)text, ...;` and `- (void)log:(NSString *)text withArguments:(va_list)list;`

Comment: @yar as a general rule, whenever you find yourself writing a function or method that accepts ..., it's probably a good idea to also make a version that accepts a va_list and have the former invoke the latter. You get more flexibility that way. :)