# generalize call to NSLog

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos, nslog

I am tying to generalize calling NSLog and avoid having to comment-out the calls when I am finished debugging.

I have:

```
#define USE_ADLog 0
#define USE_RPLog 0
#define USE_DLLog 1

void ConsoleADLog(NSString *message, ...);
void ConsoleRPLog(NSString *message, ...);
void ConsoleDLLog(NSString *message, ...);
```

and, for example:

```
void ConsoleADLog(NSString *message, ...) {

#if (USE_ADLog)
    va_list optionalArgs;

    va_start(optionalArgs, message);   // after the parm = message
    va_end(optionalArgs);

    NSLog(message, optionalArgs);
#endif
}
```

So far, so good ... however, as soon as I call, for example,:

```
   ConsoleDLLog(@"parm1 = %@, parm2 = %@", parm1, parm2);
```

which call is inside a secondary thread, I bomb.  I thought?? that va_start, va_end were thread safe.

... or is the problem %@ ... I know %f works ???

Apparently not!, so how do I make them thread safe ... plain ole

```
NSLog(@"whatever %@", whateverParm)
```

works, but not the function above.

Thanks,

Comment: Check this topic: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks

Comment: Several things I don't understand. Why are you releasing optionalArgs in va_end before using it? shouldn't you save it with something like `msg = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:message arguments:optionalArgs] autorelease]; va_end(optionalArgs);` then NSLog the msg? Do you really want NSLog for the ASL? you could use fprintf instead.

Answer (score 1):

this is why many variadic functions include variants which accept `va_list`s.

see `NSLogv`.

Comment: Amen ... used NSLogv(@"whatever %@, whateverParm) and all became good ... BUT, since NSLog just calls NSLogv, why doesn't using NSLog here work.  I know that "Ours is not to reason why, etc. etc." ... but WHY?

Comment: see QA in accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143906/how-to-use-va-args-to-pass-arguments-on-variadic-parameters-elipsis

Comment: Thanks, Justin ... The WHY? comes from Yuji "You can't. Once ... is converted to va_list, it can be only passed to a function or a method which accepts va_list, not to a function/method which accepts a variable number of parameters."

Comment: vas are opaque and implementation defined. furthermore, va initialization operates uses local addresses - there is no explicit storage to specify (pass by argument to the function) a user defined address (e.g. the address of the external function's first argument in the valist). if you wanted to forward this info, you could do so by adding an argument to all your variadic functions, but that is more complex than adding va_list variants (imo).

Answer (score 0):

```
#if DEBUG == 0
#define DebugLog(...)
#elif DEBUG == 1
#define DebugLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Then invoke it using `DebugLog(@"Uh oh: %@", someArgument);`.  If `DEBUG` is set to `1`, the preprocessor will emit `NSLog(@"Uh oh: %@", someArgument);`.  If it's set to `0`, it will not emit anything.

Comment: Forgive me because I just don't remember the specifics ... but, with Xcode 4 (not with 3) the line #define DebugLog(...) with an empty equivalent produced some sort of (extraterrestial) warning about something.  Darn, I wish I could remember!