# How to override a variadic method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variadic, variadic-functions

I'm trying to extend a class that has a variadic method such as:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)arguments, ... ;
```

and in the subclass override it by calling the original method like:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)arguments, ... {
    [super someMethod:arguments, ...];

    // override implementation
    ...
}
```

but this doesn't work. Anyone know how to work this? Thanks.

Comment: So... Is this a category, or a superclass?  Because Categories EXTEND and superclasses OVERSEE.

Comment: It's not possible generally to wrap a variadic function or method like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C passing around ... nil terminated argument lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345196/objective-c-passing-around-nil-terminated-argument-lists)

Comment: And see the question linked to in a comment there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143906/how-to-use-va-args-to-pass-arguments-on-variadic-parameters-elipsis

Comment: Thanks, you're right, it's actually written: "If you don't have a function analagous to vfprintf that takes a va_list instead of a variable number of arguments, you can't do it."

Answer (score 3):

similar to `printf`/`vprintf`, the base would declare:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)arguments, ... ;
```

the subclass would implement:

```
- (void)vsomeMethod:(id)arguments vaList:(va_list)vaList;
```

then the base would just call `vsomeMethod:vaList:` in its implementation of `someMethod:vaList:`.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the base class cannot be modified.

Comment: @TaketoSano it would be just like implementing a variadic function, but you would forward the `va_list` to `vsomeMethod:vaList:` after creating it, rather than enumerating the arguments. since you cannot modify the base, this approach won't work for you because `someMethod:` must be defined by the base in order to forward properly. the only remaining 'workarounds' that I know of are implementation-defined.

Comment: Great answer, though I might lead with "you can't." ;)